# Wordpress AJAX call always returns 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to make an AJAX call within WP, though I always get '0' as the return value. I've looked through SO and WP Stack Exchange but still haven't had any luck with this.

Steps that I have taken:

- including die() or wp_die() at the end of php script
- deleting both contentType: false, and processData: false
- altering data: fd, so it does not pass in the 'fd' variable, but an actual object with the needed information
- verified the ajax url 'ajax_object.ajax_url'

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**JS FILE**

```
  let fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("action", "user_zip");
  fd.append("security", ajax_object.ajax_nonce);
  fd.append("zip", zip);

  $.ajax({
    url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
    data: fd,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
  });
```

**PHP File**

```
function userZip()
{
    wp_verify_nonce('ajax_file_nonce', 'security');
    
    echo 'Test';
    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_user_zip', 'userZip');
add_action('wp_ajax_user_zip', 'userZip');
```

Comment: Did you localize your ajax object?

Comment: I believe so. There are other ajax calls in the file that I am working in, and they work just fine. Only this particular one doesn't work.

Comment: Cool. Sometimes it's something simple. I don't see anything wrong with what you have currently. What is `FormData()` doing?

Comment: For what it's worth when I go to the url: ajax_object.ajax_url , that particular page displays a 0 and in devtools displays an 400 error (bad request). Though I'm not sure where to go from there if the request on my end is ok.

Comment: FormData() is building the object to pass as a parameter in AJAX call.